# Guard, how to temporally track specific file?

Tags: ruby, guard

I'm using [Guard gem](https://github.com/guard/guard)

At some time of development I need to track only a specific file or several files but not an entire project.

Is there some handy way to temporarily track a particular file?

I know it can be done by modifying guard file but I don't think it's a neat solution.

Comment: Please elaborate on why you're looking for this solution.  Also, will it always be tracking a single file, or could you imagine wanting to toggle tracking on multiple files?

Comment: In case when I have a lot of broken tests the guard will bring me a mess of messages. That's why I want to get only messages from files I'm working on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually you can just use `focus: true` in the `it` statement for instance:

In your Spec file.

```
it "needs to focus on this!", focus: true do
  #test written here.
end
```

Then in spec/spec_helper you need to add the config option.

```
RSpec.configure do |config| 
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true  
  config.filter_run :focus => true  
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true 
end
```

Then Guard will automatically pick up test that is focused and run it only. Also the `config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true` tells guard to run all of the tests when there is nothing filtered even though the name sounds misleading.

I find Ryan Bate's rails casts to be very helpful on [Guard](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/264-guard) and [Spork](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/285-spork).

Comment: Many thanks for this, that last config variable is horribly misleading.

Suggested edit: Because `config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values` is on, the spec line `it "needs to focus on this!", focus: => true do`
can be shortened to `it "needs to focus on this!", :focus do`

Comment: For rspec 3 `config.filter_run_when_matching :focus` is enough, and "When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples get run."

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [groups](https://github.com/guard/guard#group) will work for you?

```
# In your Guardfile
group :focus do
  guard :ruby do
    watch('file_to_focus_on.rb')
  end
end

# Run it with
guard -g focus
```

I know you mentioned you don't want to modify the Guardfile, but adding a group would just need to be done once, not every time you switch from watching the project to a focused set and back.

Of course if the set of files you need to focus on changes, you'll need to change the args to `watch` (and maybe add more watchers), but I figure you'll have to specify them somewhere and this seems as good a place as any.

Alternately, if you really don't want to list the files to focus on in the Guardfile, you could have the *:focus* group read in a list of files from a separate file or an environment variable as suggested by David [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14650674/2004045).  The Guardfile is just plain ruby (with access to the guard DSL), so it's easy to read a file or ENV variable.

Comment: I like it, but it produce error - Could not load 'guard/ruby' or find class Guard::Ruby. I couldn't resolve this, any thoughts?

Comment: I changed guard :ruby to guard 'rspec', at the beginning guard runs the right file but then it runs all tests, so nothing changed very much.

Comment: The ruby guard plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/JustinLove/guard-ruby).  With the guard-rspec plugin there are several ways to focus on a few files. @oto-brglez has described one way in a separate answer that makes use of rspec commandline options. The guard-rspec readme has a [section](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#running-a-subset-of-all-specs) on running a subset.  Let me know if these pointers don't work for you and i can update the answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec). You can do this.

Change your [Guardfile](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#guardfile) rspec block so that is has something like this:

```
guard 'rspec', :cli => ENV['RSPEC_e'].nil? ? "": "-e #{ENV['RSPEC_e']}") do
  # ... regular rspec-rails stuff goes here ...
end
```

Start Guard. And set **RSPEC_e** before. Like so...

```
RSPEC_e=here guard
```

Then whenever you change something only specs that have text "here" (set by RSPEC_e) in their description will be re-run.

Comment: There's also the [--tag option](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/tag-option!) which might be simpler than the above.  `guard 'rspec', :cli => '-t focus' do ...` and it will run only examples tagged with focus => true, e.g. `it "is giving me trouble", :focus => true do ...`

Comment: Yeah tags would also work nicely, but then u have to tag your specs. If u use -e you can just match text...

Answer (score 0):

You could permanently modify the guard file to check an environment variable of your choosing and behave differently if it is present.  For example, access the variable ENV['FILE'].  Then you can prepend your command for running guard with `FILE=foo.rb` whenever you want.